# Troubles setting up fixed IP on Debian 12 VM

Tags: debian, networking, network-interface, networkmanager, systemd-networkd

I've got Debian 12 VM running on an Macbook (M2) using **Lima**. I have added a 2nd network to it which created a `lima0` network interface in the the Debian VM. By default it tries to get its address from DHCP but there are known issues with that in Lima on M2 Mac so I decided to assign a static IP instead. But I struggle to do that.

I can add the IP manually with `ip a add 192.168.106.2/24 dev lima0` and it works:

```
$ ip addr show dev lima0
3: lima0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:55:55:ff:13:b4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.106.2/24 scope global lima0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

However I can't find a way to do this automatically after VM startup.

First I tried creating `/etc/network/interfaces` with this content, no luck.

```
allow-hotplug lima0
iface lima0 inet manual
  up ip a add 192.168.106.2/24 dev lima0
```

Then I tried `nmcli`:

```
$ sudo nmcli device modify lima0 ip4 192.168.106.2/24
Error: Reading applied connection from device 'lima0' 
       (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3) 
       failed: Device is not activated
```

Also tried to create a new device config with `nmtui` but activating that also failed with something like "device lima0 is strictly unmanaged" or something like that.

I can see the device both in `systemctl` and in `nmcli` but can't find a way to manage it.

```
$ sudo systemctl status sys-subsystem-net-devices-lima0.device
● sys-subsystem-net-devices-lima0.device - Virtio network device
     Loaded: loaded
     Active: active (plugged) since Mon 2024-01-29 21:55:21 UTC; 4min 22s ago
     Device: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/virtio2/net/lima0
```

and ...

```
$ sudo nmcli device show lima0
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lima0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         52:55:55:FF:13:B4
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::5055:55ff:feff:13b4/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
```

Any idea how to set the static IP automatically after the boot?

--

**Update:** this seems to do the trick through Network Manager but doesn't survive the reboot:

```
$ sudo nmcli device set lima0 autoconnect yes managed yes
$ sudo nmcli device modify lima0 ipv4.method manual ipv4.addr 192.168.106.2/24
Connection successfully reapplied to device 'lima0'.
```

How do I make this persistent?

Comment: have you removed the settings in `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, removed it after I figured out that it didn't help.

Comment: and you've restarted networking (or rebooted the VM)?

Comment: @JaromandaX I have rebooted many times

Comment: Sure, ok, just ticking all the boxes :p

Comment: @JaromandaX added a little updated with `nmcli` if it helps..

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1456572/network-device-is-strictly-unmanaged-trying-to-make-static-ip-work

Comment: Did you read [debian's wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Configuring_the_interface_manually) ?

Comment: @user4089 which part that isn’t already covered in my question?